# Print pandas column name and cell value row wise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to split up a pandas dataframe by row into headed paragraphs. The column name is the heading and the cell value is the paragraph.

Example df (the actual df is much longer)

```
data = {'Title': ['Wormwood', 'Transmetropolitan', 'Y - The last man'],
    'Author': ['Ben Templesmith', 'Warren Ellis', 'Brian K. Vaughan'],
    'Abstract' :['Blah blah', 'Yadda yadda', 'Alas, poor Yorick! I knew him....']}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Title', 'Author', 'Abstract'])
```

my desired output is

---

Title:
Wormwood

Author:
Ben Templesmith

Abstract:
Blah blah

Title:
Transmetropolitan

Author:
Warren Ellis

Abstract:
Yadda yadda

Title:
Y-the last man

Author:
Brian K. Vaughan

Abstract:
Alas, poor Yorick! I knew him....

---

Code I've tried

```
for i,j in zip(range(len(df.columns), range(len(df)):
    print(f'***{df.columns[i]}***\n  {df.iloc[j][j]}')
    i+=1
    j+=1
```

This kind of works but it seems really clunky and won't work on a longer more complex df.

For context, I'm basically trying to turn this df into a small booklet if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape, then remove index repeated values by first `reset_index` with `drop=True` and set new columns names:

```
df1 = df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')
print (df1)
          a                                  b
0     Title                           Wormwood
1    Author                    Ben Templesmith
2  Abstract                          Blah blah
3     Title                  Transmetropolitan
4    Author                       Warren Ellis
5  Abstract                        Yadda yadda
6     Title                   Y - The last man
7    Author                   Brian K. Vaughan
8  Abstract  Alas, poor Yorick! I knew him....
```

Then is necessary print in `f-string`s:

```
for a, b in df1.to_numpy():
    print (f'{a}: {b}')
    Title: Wormwood
Author: Ben Templesmith
Abstract: Blah blah
Title: Transmetropolitan
Author: Warren Ellis
Abstract: Yadda yadda
Title: Y - The last man
Author: Brian K. Vaughan
Abstract: Alas, poor Yorick! I knew him....
```